# Configure valgrind to only do leak checks

Tags: valgrind

I am trying to find a memory leak in a C library loaded by the JVM. Is it possible to configure valgrind to only do leak checks and none of the other checks. I ask because the JVM itself has a massive amount of memory errors detected by valgrind which I am not interested in.

I have attempted suppression but it seems like the JVM just keeps coming up with new errors.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following option:

> --undef-value-errors=no --show-mismatched-frees=no

Comment: It looks to still be doing invalid write checks as well

Comment: I could imagine that it might be normal to have undef values or mismatched frees false positives.  It is however not very clear how an invalid write might not indicate a real problem.  Assuming such invalid writes are really normal in the JVM, then what you can do is to have a suppression file with one supp entry suppressing all invalid write errors. You will then however also suppress invalid writes in your C library.  Same remark for the above options: if ever your C library has such bugs, you will not detect them.  Working with a suppression file looks better.